# Implement bootstrap on framework that already has styles

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a php framework that generates inputs with classes for it's css.
All the HTML elements are already defined with styles, but it's ugly and I want to use bootstrap.

Is there an easier way to implement bootstrap to the my website without renaming all the selectors in the bootstrap CSS?

Thanks,
Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include Bootstrap **BEFORE** your custom default styling. Any `CSS` in your custom file will override the `CSS` in Bootstrap. Then, you can tweak as needed.

If you prefer the default Bootstrap styles, include the Bootstrap `CSS` **AFTER** your other `CSS` files, and then delegate priority as desired.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this won't work for elements like buttons or tables, my tables have the class `datagrid` and bootstrap uses `table` and/or a second class for more styles. What can I do for those elements?

Comment: You can either use something like jQuery to remove the `datagrid` and other classes when the page loads, or copy the desired styles from bootstrap into a custom `CSS` file